# Fresh Win7 installed with SSD. All known drivers updated - high hard pagefaults

Tags: windows-7, drivers, dpc

I previously had a thread with nasty pagefaults where the main culprit was my HDD was actually failing. I received a new SSD this week and reinstalled Windows 7, since then things have been insanely faster. I went from very low settings in multiple games with hiccups to max settings. It's really depressing how long the bad HDD had been bottlenecking my performance and I was in denial.

ANYWAYS, Latencymon posted below as well as an xperf going to be pasted. Would love any help on where to look next, I've installed all drivers I could think of. SSD has been updated to most recent firmware, Intel Speed Tech has been disabled in BIOS and the bios is up to date (Sabertooth p67 3602 version). High Performance has been selected in Windows as well.

XPERF: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B597DIrOwkw0UHF2THlQaGlESk0/view?usp=sharing

```
CONCLUSION
_________________________________________________________________________________________________________
Your system seems to have difficulty handling real-time audio and other tasks. You may experience drop outs, clicks or pops due to buffer underruns. One problem may be related to power management, disable CPU throttling settings in Control Panel and BIOS setup. Check for BIOS updates. 
LatencyMon has been analyzing your system for  0:02:02  (h:mm:ss) on all processors.


_________________________________________________________________________________________________________
SYSTEM INFORMATION
_________________________________________________________________________________________________________
Computer name:                                        TRISTIANLEW
OS version:                                           Windows 7 Service Pack 1, 6.1, build: 7601 (x64)
Hardware:                                             ASUSTeK Computer INC., SABERTOOTH P67
CPU:                                                  GenuineIntel Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600K CPU @ 3.40GHz
Logical processors:                                   8
Processor groups:                                     1
RAM:                                                  12255 MB total


_________________________________________________________________________________________________________
CPU SPEED
_________________________________________________________________________________________________________
Reported CPU speed:                                   3407.0 MHz
Measured CPU speed:                                   2859.0 MHz (approx.)

Note: reported execution times may be calculated based on a fixed reported CPU speed. Disable variable speed settings like Intel Speed Step and AMD Cool N Quiet in the BIOS setup for more accurate results.


_________________________________________________________________________________________________________
MEASURED INTERRUPT TO USER PROCESS LATENCIES
_________________________________________________________________________________________________________
The interrupt to process latency reflects the measured interval that a usermode process needed to respond to a hardware request from the moment the interrupt service routine started execution. This includes the scheduling and execution of a DPC routine, the signaling of an event and the waking up of a usermode thread from an idle wait state in response to that event.

Highest measured interrupt to process latency (µs):   1115.986248
Average measured interrupt to process latency (µs):   2.764362

Highest measured interrupt to DPC latency (µs):       182.091456
Average measured interrupt to DPC latency (µs):       0.893639


_________________________________________________________________________________________________________
 REPORTED ISRs
_________________________________________________________________________________________________________
Interrupt service routines are routines installed by the OS and device drivers that execute in response to a hardware interrupt signal.

Highest ISR routine execution time (µs):              209.179043
Driver with highest ISR routine execution time:       dxgkrnl.sys - DirectX Graphics Kernel, Microsoft Corporation

Highest reported total ISR routine time (%):          0.033012
Driver with highest ISR total time:                   dxgkrnl.sys - DirectX Graphics Kernel, Microsoft Corporation

Total time spent in ISRs (%)                          0.065645

ISR count (execution time <250 µs):                   153822
ISR count (execution time 250-500 µs):                0
ISR count (execution time 500-999 µs):                0
ISR count (execution time 1000-1999 µs):              0
ISR count (execution time 2000-3999 µs):              0
ISR count (execution time >=4000 µs):                 0


_________________________________________________________________________________________________________
REPORTED DPCs
_________________________________________________________________________________________________________
DPC routines are part of the interrupt servicing dispatch mechanism and disable the possibility for a process to utilize the CPU while it is interrupted until the DPC has finished execution.

Highest DPC routine execution time (µs):              270.250073
Driver with highest DPC routine execution time:       tcpip.sys - TCP/IP Driver, Microsoft Corporation

Highest reported total DPC routine time (%):          0.038182
Driver with highest DPC total execution time:         USBPORT.SYS - USB 1.1 & 2.0 Port Driver, Microsoft Corporation

Total time spent in DPCs (%)                          0.133808

DPC count (execution time <250 µs):                   567636
DPC count (execution time 250-500 µs):                0
DPC count (execution time 500-999 µs):                1
DPC count (execution time 1000-1999 µs):              0
DPC count (execution time 2000-3999 µs):              0
DPC count (execution time >=4000 µs):                 0


_________________________________________________________________________________________________________
 REPORTED HARD PAGEFAULTS
_________________________________________________________________________________________________________
Hard pagefaults are events that get triggered by making use of virtual memory that is not resident in RAM but backed by a memory mapped file on disk. The process of resolving the hard pagefault requires reading in the memory from disk while the process is interrupted and blocked from execution.

NOTE: some processes were hit by hard pagefaults. If these were programs producing audio, they are likely to interrupt the audio stream resulting in dropouts, clicks and pops. Check the Processes tab to see which programs were hit.

Process with highest pagefault count:                 svchost.exe

Total number of hard pagefaults                       343
Hard pagefault count of hardest hit process:          89
Highest hard pagefault resolution time (µs):          61875.318168
Total time spent in hard pagefaults (%):              0.042098
Number of processes hit:                              11


_________________________________________________________________________________________________________
 PER CPU DATA
_________________________________________________________________________________________________________
CPU 0 Interrupt cycle time (s):                       3.493773
CPU 0 ISR highest execution time (µs):                209.179043
CPU 0 ISR total execution time (s):                   0.645163
CPU 0 ISR count:                                      153822
CPU 0 DPC highest execution time (µs):                245.619607
CPU 0 DPC total execution time (s):                   1.250163
CPU 0 DPC count:                                      545089
_________________________________________________________________________________________________________
CPU 1 Interrupt cycle time (s):                       1.547568
CPU 1 ISR highest execution time (µs):                0.0
CPU 1 ISR total execution time (s):                   0.0
CPU 1 ISR count:                                      0
CPU 1 DPC highest execution time (µs):                270.250073
CPU 1 DPC total execution time (s):                   0.003498
CPU 1 DPC count:                                      407
_________________________________________________________________________________________________________
CPU 2 Interrupt cycle time (s):                       1.335016
CPU 2 ISR highest execution time (µs):                0.0
CPU 2 ISR total execution time (s):                   0.0
CPU 2 ISR count:                                      0
CPU 2 DPC highest execution time (µs):                205.423540
CPU 2 DPC total execution time (s):                   0.015915
CPU 2 DPC count:                                      5349
_________________________________________________________________________________________________________
CPU 3 Interrupt cycle time (s):                       1.739508
CPU 3 ISR highest execution time (µs):                0.0
CPU 3 ISR total execution time (s):                   0.0
CPU 3 ISR count:                                      0
CPU 3 DPC highest execution time (µs):                178.61990
CPU 3 DPC total execution time (s):                   0.002303
CPU 3 DPC count:                                      260
_________________________________________________________________________________________________________
CPU 4 Interrupt cycle time (s):                       0.946584
CPU 4 ISR highest execution time (µs):                0.0
CPU 4 ISR total execution time (s):                   0.0
CPU 4 ISR count:                                      0
CPU 4 DPC highest execution time (µs):                164.648665
CPU 4 DPC total execution time (s):                   0.020333
CPU 4 DPC count:                                      7698
_________________________________________________________________________________________________________
CPU 5 Interrupt cycle time (s):                       1.600787
CPU 5 ISR highest execution time (µs):                0.0
CPU 5 ISR total execution time (s):                   0.0
CPU 5 ISR count:                                      0
CPU 5 DPC highest execution time (µs):                0.0
CPU 5 DPC total execution time (s):                   0.0
CPU 5 DPC count:                                      0
_________________________________________________________________________________________________________
CPU 6 Interrupt cycle time (s):                       1.035665
CPU 6 ISR highest execution time (µs):                0.0
CPU 6 ISR total execution time (s):                   0.0
CPU 6 ISR count:                                      0
CPU 6 DPC highest execution time (µs):                163.171705
CPU 6 DPC total execution time (s):                   0.022867
CPU 6 DPC count:                                      8834
_________________________________________________________________________________________________________
CPU 7 Interrupt cycle time (s):                       1.814152
CPU 7 ISR highest execution time (µs):                0.0
CPU 7 ISR total execution time (s):                   0.0
CPU 7 ISR count:                                      0
CPU 7 DPC highest execution time (µs):                0.0
CPU 7 DPC total execution time (s):                   0.0
CPU 7 DPC count:                                      0
_________________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Page faults cannot be fixed with drivers, HDD firmware etc., it is the result of high peak memory consumption. Although it is called a "fault" it is not a failure.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the info. For the most part I get that, I suppose I'm trying to understand two things, is it 'normal' to get a few hundred pagefaults when loading up programs? The other part would be to understand if getting ~100k ISR count for hal.dll a minute is normal. I use a Wireless N USB adapter in the front of my case in a USB 3.0 slot for the internet. When this is disabled I still get pagefaults but the Latencymon report comes back fine with no high reports of latency although the ISR counts are roughly the same. It is currently my only means of internet in a 3 story building.

Comment: I also just want to add performance wise my PC seems entirely stable. I replaced the HDD this week and that seemed to be the huge cause of any problems, but since numbers wise everything in LatencyMon looks the same I just want to make sure there isnt anything else wrong with my machine currently.

Comment: I'd read up on what a page fault is before getting worried about them - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault They are a 'natural' part of how your OS handles memory requirements, using memory as files 'paged' to disk instead of real physical RAM.